# Accessing nested associative array with unknown keys

Tags: php, object, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access elements from a multidimensional array in an object.  For example, let's assume there is some class Foo that has a variable called $phone that represents the multidimensional array.

```
$phone -> structure will look like
Array {
  "home" Array(1) {[0] = "555-1212"},
  "work" Array(2) {[0] = "555-1234", [1] = "555=5434"},
  "other" Array(1) {[0] = "555=9090"}
}
```

Note: We can't assume we know the keys.

I can access a value by giving explicit keys, i.e.,

```
$foo->phone["home"][0]
```

The problem comes to when I don't explicitly know the keys and pull them from elsewhere.
For example if $type="phone", $subtype = "home", and I want the first entry I would expect to use:

```
$object->$type[$subtype][0]
```

to get the value, but I get an error and it doesn't think it is an array.  I am not sure where the error is.

The next thing would be to add elements to the lowest level array.  I assume the following would work, but doesn't:

```
array_push($object->$type[$subtype], $value)
```

This mutidimensional array would allow me to store phone numbers labelled by keys in a single nested structure.  If this is overcomplicating the issue please let me know.  The reason I chose this structure is because the keys can be anything the user customizes.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say; 'the keys can be anything the user customizes', are you saying that the form they using to submit this information allows them to set the keys?

Comment: Yes.  There would be some other method that allows a user to create a key.  For example "Home Fax", and then add a number or numbers to it.  It is meant to work like Apple's Address book.  I can add a customized field for a phone number and define by own key.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work if you save $object->$type as it's own variable, then access that variable to go deeper in the array.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it.  For more information, here is how I try to create the structure, which also doesn't work ... Sorry for the formatting.

    `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $type = $this->$row['type'];

      // Check to see if this key exists in the object array
      if(!array_key_exists($row['title'], $type)) {
        $type[$row['title']] = array();
      }

      // Add the value to the object array
      if(is_array($type[$row['title']])) {
        array_push($type[$row['title']], $r)
      }
    }`

Comment: shouldn't it be `$type = $row['type'];`? Otherwise save $row['type'] to a var first: `$rowType = $row['type']; $type = $this->$rowType;`

Comment: It looks like that is in the correct direction.  The arrays have stuff in them.  Why do I need to generate a variable for each level in the structure?  Why can't I just do something like `$this->$row['type'][$row['title']]`?

Comment: Because PHP parses it as `($this->$row)['type']`. In other words, it tries to find a member variable with the name of the value of `$row`. It assumes that's an array and tries to get the value with a key of 'type'.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I ended up inserting a few conditionals to eliminate a level of abstraction that really wasn't required.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out :)